# How can i identify player on udp connection

Tags: java, udp

I am building a multiplayer game using java, TCP part i have figured out and it works like charm.

I have read Source Multiplayer Networking by Valve. In my game i will have to send 20/30 packets per second. Since UDP is connection less how to "identify" which player which is?

Lets say i have room with 5 players and i have to send data to each player. How can i "known" their addresses?

I thought about "saving" their ip address and port but as far as read about udp it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the player id in the message.  e.g. the first byte could be the source.

As UDP is a lossy protocol, you need to think about how you are going to handle corrupt or missing packets, and adding a source is to the header can be part of that.

Comment: You can't seem to understand me. I have 5 players online and Player1 send new position and rotation. I can easy send data to Player1, what i am asking is how to access other 4 players and update them